# Jquery UI autocomplete success but doesn't show text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I fetch data via Ajax for jquery autocomplete, it works and when I begin to type on the input it displays bullet points under the input. No text, no styling, just bullet points but the right amount of bullet points per how many results there should be. It's very confusing. The data is being retrieved as an array of objects so maybe that has something to do with it. But I tried returning just the values and no joy.

PHP:

```
function getArtistNamesByInput($connection, $input) {
    $names = array();

    $name = "%".$input."%";

    $query = "SELECT first_name, second_name, third_name, last_name FROM artists WHERE first_name LIKE ?";
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($firstName, $secondName, $thirdName, $lastName);
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
      $names[] = array(
        "name" => $firstName." ".$secondName." ".$thirdName." ".$lastName
      );
    }
    $stmt->close();
    return json_encode($names);
  }
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('#artist').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/modules/ajax/ajax_handler.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
          action: 'getArtistNamesByInput',
          input: $('#artist').val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
          var result = JSON.parse(data);
          console.log(result);
          response(result);
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: can you include the output of console.log(result)

Comment: `(2) [{…}, {…}]` and when expanded `0: {name: "Thomas   Markey"}
1: {name: "Thomas   Brezing"}`

Comment: Try converting result into an array format before passing it as source to autocomplete

Comment: Has this been resolved? What was the solution?

Comment: @AlwaysaLearner No i couldnt get it working so used a `select` input instead

Comment: Cool... I like to use select instead of Autocomplete unless I want to give an option to enter a new value, which can also be done in HTML5 without autocomplete